# Can I add a command to my bash profile whenever I create a new folder?

Tags: bash, cd

I've been creating commands that jet me to my folder I want to work within, and it's great, but...
Could there be a way to add the command automatically whenever I create a new folder?
E.g., I make a folder on my comp, and this gets added to my bash profile:

alias foldername='cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/foldername/wp-content/themes/foldername'

I'm on a mac; el capitan.

Comment: If you only create new folders with `mkdir`, then sure, alias `mkdir` to a function wrapper or write a wrapper script, although what you're trying to do is completely paranoid and has many ramifications (aliases overriding builtins and external commands, big runcom, duplicate aliases overriding each other, dangling aliases pointing to nowhere, so on and so forth). If you want to have this when you create new folders with Finder, then no, especially not after SIP.

Comment: What you might want is to try one of the myriad tools designed to speed up navigation in shell: `fasd` (what I use), `autojump`, `z`, etc.

Comment: Be wary of making something that could alias important commands. What if you make a directory called `ls`?  :-)

Comment: @ghoti ... or a directory called *alias* :D

Comment: Be wary of autogenerating `aliases` anywhere. It's far to easy to end up with conflicting aliases or aliases that mask system or other executables. A general alias that creates a directory and then changes to that directory on successful creation is fine. When you work within your filesystem enough, you will find there are probably 10-20 directories you work from/below most often. I would limit the hardcoded aliases there just to prevent surprises.

Comment: @hek2mgl - [I like it!](https://github.com/ayust/underhanded/blob/master/.bashrc) :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function in your `.bashrc`:

```
# Changes directory to project in htdocs
function project () {
    cd "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/$1"
}
```

Once you've sourced the bashrc or started a new shell you can navigate through to sub folders of htdocs using

```
project FOLDER_NAME
```

Comment: Or, just add `CDPATH=.:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs` to you ~/.bash_profile, then simply `cd FOLDER_NAME`

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to install a newer version of `bash` (via Homebrew, for instance), you can set the `autocd` option.

```
$ shopt -s autocd
$ pwd
/Users/me
$ mkdir foo
$ foo
cd foo
$ pwd
/Users/me/foo
```

The version of `zsh` that ships with Mac OS X has an identically named option, if you are willing to change shells.

```
% setopt autocd
% pwd
/Users/me
% mkdir foo
% foo
% pwd
/Users/me/foo
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `CDPATH` environment variable for this sort of thing (assuming your target directories live under a common directory (or three).

From the POSIX specification for [`cd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html#tag_20_14_08):

> ```
> CDPATH
> ```
>
> A <colon>-separated list of pathnames that refer to directories. The *cd* utility shall use this list in its attempt to change the directory, as described in the DESCRIPTION. An empty string in place of a directory pathname represents the current directory. If *CDPATH* is not set, it shall be treated as if it were an empty string.

So if you set `CDPATH=.:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/foldername/wp-content/themes` you could then just use `cd foldername` from anywhere to go to `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/foldername/wp-content/themes/foldername`... assuming of course that there wasn't a directory `foldername` in your current directory (if you wanted it to work for that too you would need to invert the order of the items in `CDPATH`).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach referenced in the comment is the create a simple function that creates and changes to a directory. Aliased to `mdcd` it does just that creates and on successful creation changes to the directory. I use it in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
mkdircd ()
{
    [ -z "$1" ] && {
        printf "usage: mdcd <dir>\n";
        return 1
    }
    mkdir -p "$1" && cd "$1" || {
        printf "error: unable to create directory '%s'\n" "$1";
        return 1
    }
    return 0
}

...

alias mdcd='mkdircd'
```

You can give it a try and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: I personally have a very similar function called `mkcd`, so thumbs up, but this really has nothing to do with what's asked...

Comment: That was a close call, but the question asked to do something that has a significant potential to cause problems with his system, as explained in the comment. This was a follow-on to the explanation in the comment which when I considered whether it was better to attempt to cram it all into the comment or post as an answer, the latter seemed the better choice.

Comment: Lots to digest here. I'll probably stick with my current method if there's any chance I can screw things up. Thanks for all the answers.